# How to create Java application with dependencies manually

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka

I have created a java application for kafka using maven. I present the java code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;

import java.util.Properties;

public class pega {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "first-app");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> order = builder.stream("input-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()))
                .selectKey((k,v) -> v);
        order.to("output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()));

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties);
        streams.start();

        System.out.println(streams.toString());

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }
}
```

The way that I have created this project is through IntelliJ IDE. Now I want to create the same project, in an environment with no internet access and the only way for installing software and applications is through requests to a maintenance team. So, in order to make the requests, many questions have arisen.
But before I proceed, I present a part of the pom.xml.

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
...
```

What IntelliJ is doing when I write this pom.xml is downloading the Kafka streams package from the internet.

**Questions**

1) Where are these packages stored and where is maven looking for packages locally?

2) Is the repository that maven is looking to, the same that java has its default packages stored?

3) If maven is installed, does it work fine without internet access, if all the dependencies are on the local repository?

4) If I wanted to create a java application without any tool, how would I handle those dependencies (like Kafka streams)? (In case maven can not be installed).

Comment: A lot of questions, but what became of 2) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The maven packages are stored in:

1. Windows: C:\Users\.m2
2. Linux: /home/user_name/.m2
3. Mac: /Users/user_name/.m2

You will find the maven package in the following path: /home/user_name/.m2/repository/org/commonjava/maven

2) The common core java packages and plugins are at the same path at which the Maven looks into.

3) Once the packages are downloaded you can work without any internet access.

4) You need to use a particular tool to handle those dependencies, it will make your work easier. If not maven, you can use Gradle only if it supports the service or dependency that you are trying to use. (I am not sure whether Gradle has some libraries for handling the Kafka dependencies).